# Php/MYSql Error in Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I there any problem on my code??? If its ok then why i am always get this error

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'add = 'Myaddress' WHERE id = '' at line 7 in
>   C:****\class\class.admin.php on line 160

Here is my Code:

```
function EditClient($uname,$email,$pname,$cname,$mob,$add,$cid)
    {
        $query = $this->dbh->prepare("
                UPDATE client SET 
                uname = :username,
                email = :email,
                pname = :pname,
                cname = :cname,
                mob = :mob,
                add = :addr
                WHERE id = :id ");


        $query->execute(array(
                ':username' => $uname,
                ':email' => $email,
                ':pname' => $pname,
                ':cname' => $cname,
                ':mob' => $mob,
                ':addr' => $add,
                ':id' => $cid
                )); //here is the line 160

        return $query->rowCount();
    }
```

Where the value of $cid is "Myaddress"

Comment: `add` is reserve word in mysql

Comment: @AshishBiswas Never forget accept/upvote if answer is helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: Yep, after got this fix now i understand its look like duplicate of this question which you mentioned, but at the time when i was posting this never thought about reserve word. BTW thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by using a reserved word `ADD`

```
add = :addr
```

You need to back-tick it

```
`add` = :addr
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: :P Thanks. I have totally forget this.

Answer (score 2):

In mySql `add` is reserve word so you need to change

```
add = :addr
```

to

```
`add` = :addr
```

add back-tick on `add` keyword as mentioned above.

Check [<kbd>**Manual**</kbd>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) for Reserve word in mysql.